# find the default database file on calling create table on android

Tags: android

I wrote some code that creates table if not exist.

I can't understand how it works on android. I want to know where it creates the table and how can I see it ( using some tool - maybe tool that exist on android studio ) that will show me all the table that exists on this database/database file

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

  String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COLUMN_DATE_AS_TEXT + " TEXT);";

  try {
     db.execSQL(query);
  } catch (Exception e) {
     String eee = e.getMessage();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The databases created for an app cannot be viewed in a physical device. But you can see them when running it in a virtual device. In eclipse go to **DDMS tab** --> **File Explorer Tab** --> **expand data** --> **expand data** --> **Search for your package name** --> **Expand databases**.

Comment: I using galaxy s7 device - and i don't see nothing on the 'data' expand - no files on it

Comment: I have clearly stated above that it is not possible to view application databases on a physical device, that is on a mobile device. You can view databases when you run your app in a virtual device.

Answer (score 1):

The database usually resides in:

```
/data/data/yourapppackagename/databases/
```

You can't access it via Android Studio except you have a root access for the device. You can use [Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) library to enable viewing the database via Chrome Developer Tools.